# How does Wordpress know to tell you that someone else has already opened a post when you do?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I'm working on a custom CMS and I like this Wordpress feature so only one person can edit a post at a time and letting others know that this post is currently being worked on by someone else.

I can't seem to find any information on this anywhere on the internet so I don't even have some sample code to post here.

Does anyone know how Wordpress does that?

Thanks!

Comment: When someone starts editing a post it marks a column in the database saying that it's being edited and by who. I'm not sure in which table, but I know I've seen it in their database structure before.

Comment: @DiddleDot thank you for you comment. Between yours and digbucc's comment I got a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

add a column to your table for "editing", make it boolean. when someone opens a post to edit, mark it as true. don't allow anyone else to edit a post marked as true. when they are done, mark it as false again.

Comment: Yeah that definitely sounds like the correct approach. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has a WP_Screen class primarily used on admin screens.

You can check out https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen